# Solving Massive Latency Issues with SQL Left Join

Tags: mysql, sql, large-data, latency

My computer is currently working toward hour 48 of a left join statement. This left join statement is to concatenate two matrices one is 47 million x 3 the other is 45 million x 2. The computer I'm running it on is a 9th gen i7 with 32gb memory and another 32gb swap.

The first table is:clsecsoneclean

```
CREATE TABLE `clsecsoneclean` (   
    `bartime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   
    `volume` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
    `cloneprice` float DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Second table is clsecstwoclean

```
CREATE TABLE `clsecstwoclean` (   
    `bartime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   
    `cltwoprice` float DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

And the output table is

stepone

```
CREATE TABLE `stepone` (   
    `bartime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   
    `volume` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,   
    `cloneprice` float DEFAULT NULL,   
    `cltwoprice` float DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

With SQL Join Statement:

```
INSERT INTO stepone 
    SELECT clsecsoneclean.bartime, clsecsoneclean.volume, 
            clsecsoneclean.cloneprice, clsecstwoclean.cltwoprice 
    FROM clsecsoneeclean 
        LEFT JOIN clsecstwoclean ON clsecsoneclean.bartime=clsecstwoclean.bartime 
    ORDER BY clsecsoneclean.bartime;
```

Is there an error with my Join statement?

Is this an improper place to use left join, in that is there a better way to accomplish this such as writing the program my self on C to accomplish this concatenation. My ultimate goal isn't that I run the program and instantly get a result but the program running faster would be a great goal of mine because these aren't the only matrices that I need to concatenate.

Comment: Remove the `order by`.

Comment: That's all and it's good?

Comment: If you make it readable, they will come and read it

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with how to format the text here on Stackoverflow

Comment: Create the index by `bartime` - in each table.

Comment: *Is there an error with my Join statement?* We do not know the logic which must be realized. So we cannot say something about the query correctness except the fact that it is synthacticalluy correct.

Comment: Two kind of errors that I'm looking for; A. if it's syntactically correct, and B. whether this is a proper use of SQL or if another program/language would be superior for realizing calculations like these, I mentioned C in the post but I'm aware there are other methods as well, eventually I know that SQL is improper once data gets large enough although I don't know where that boundary lies or if matrices in the low single digit GBs are close to that boundary.

Comment: Wow that made an impressive difference. I indexed by bartime and removed the order by and the statement just executed in 6 minutes and 32 seconds.